# wordpress rewrite rule need fix

Tags: apache, wordpress, url-rewriting

Hello I have this rewrite Rule at my Wordpress

```
RewriteRule ^trip/(.*)/$ /index.php?page_id=143&trip=$1 [L]
```

Its working but I have this problem.. when I enter page called -

`http://example.com/trip/22/?lang=en`

the $_GET['lang'] doesn't work.
I suppose that the url is becoming something like

`/index.php?page_id=143&trip=22?lang=en`

which doesn't  work.. 
Can some one advice me how to replace the question mark from `?lang=en` with & ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).